# Console returning a random word from an array, putting word in the console

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, console, document

Hi I am trying to return a random word from an array. it all works but the question prints on the screen is there any way to show the random word from the array in the command prompt box?

here is my code, it works but the question appears on the screen and not in the console. any fix??

```
    var NorthAmericaQuestions = ["How many States are in USA? Are There 51, 52, 54,           50?","How big are Dictionaries? Huge, Okayish, Thin?"]

    var NorthAmericaAnswers = [52,"Huge"]

    function RandomGen() {
        randno = Math.floor ( Math.random() * NorthAmericaQuestions.length ); 
        document.write(NorthAmericaQuestions[randno]);
}

    Q1 = prompt (RandomGen(), "Type Here!");
    if (Q1 == NorthAmericaAnswers[0]){
        document.write("<br>Thats Correct!!");
}
    else {
        document.write ("<br>Oops Your Wrong!!");
}
```

Comment: `console.log(NorthAmericaQuestions[randno])` not `document.write(NorthAmericaQuestions[randno]);`?

Comment: hi thanks for helping with that, but when placed console.log instead of document.write, it doesn't appear on the webpage which is good but how do I make it appear in the prompt box where they answer the question???

Comment: You can't using this method. Use `alert` instead if you want the answer to pop up. `alert('Answer correct!!')`. Otherwise look into using layered `div`s to produce the effect you want.

Answer (score 1):

because you write on document not in console

```
document.write(NorthAmericaQuestions[randno]);
```

it will write on the document

to write on console you have to use

```
console.log(NorthAmericaQuestions[randno]);
```

Comment: hi thanks for helping with that, but when placed console.log instead of document.write, it doesn't appear on the webpage which is good but how do I make it appear in the prompt box where they answer the question???